# SDL_PollEvent on Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-13.10, sdl-2

I've installed SDL2 from source code http://libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.3.tar.gz on Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit. It works, but the problem is that `SDL_PollEvent` function seems to clear the whole screen when called (this is not typical and also I don't want it). What's the matter?

Comment: Hum, you sure SDL_PollEvent is clearing the screen? It seems very unlikely to me.

Comment: You need to show us some code. But `SDL_PolllEvent()` does nothing to the screen unless your code tells it to.

Comment: At the end of the loop of receiving the event I call `SDL_RenderPresent`. Is that maybe the function that causes the problem? Before it (in the loop) I load some changes to the renderer, but I don't always call `SDL_RenderClear`. However, although my program works properly on Windows, on Ubuntu not.